# Get url of a taxonomy field inside an alternate shape cshtml file in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I use `Orchard 1.10.1`. I have a `CustomContentType` that has a "Group" `Taxonomy field` . In `Content-CustomContentType.Detail.cshtml` alternate, I want to have a link to a certain taxonomy term. this is my code:

```
<a href='???'>@Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0].Name</a>
```

How can I get the url to replace this `'???'` in above code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options available to you. I've just typed them all straight into the browser and Orchard is a tricky beast to navigate its model so if they blow up in your face let me know and I'll dig a bit deeper :)

### Let orchard make the entire link

Looking at the `TaxonomyItemLink.cshtml` file you can see that you can display the link like this:

```
@using Orchard.Taxonomies.Models
@{
    TermPart part = Model.ContentPart;
}
@Html.ItemDisplayLink(part)
```

So in your case you could use:

```
@Html.ItemDisplayLink((ContentPart)Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0])
```

### Just get the URL

You can use `@Url.ItemDisplayUrl()` to turn a routable content item into a url.

```
<a href="@Url.ItemDisplayUrl((ContentPart)Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0])">
  @Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0].Name
</a>
```

Because it's an extension method you can't pass a `dynamic` so you will need to cast the type. This is why the `(ContentPart)` is there.

### Just get the Slug

Actually, in this case the `TermsPart` class already has a `.Slug` property on it, so this might also work:

```
<a href="@Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0].Slug">
  @Model.ContentItem.CustomContentType.Group.Terms[0].Name
</a>
```

I'm not sure if the slug just contains the end bit or its full url though.

Comment: Thanks for answer, It worked perfectly. I used "just get the URL" but I replaced "TermPart" with "ContentPart". And I tested "Just get the Slug", Terms[0].Slug only contains relative url.

Comment: oh good :) my orchard skills are growing. I think I've seen it cast it to `IContent` as well so you don't actually need to worry about what the specific type you're dealing with is.

Comment: I updated the answer so the next copy/paster won't get caught out

Comment: You are the best :)